# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) not getting data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending push notification using **FCM** to Android device.

I'm using java based google API client for sending messages.

**FCM** request body for message using common notification object:

```
{
 "message": {
"notification": {
  "title": "FCM Notification",
  "body": "Notification from FCM"
},
"data": {
  "k1": "v1",
  "k2": "v2"
},
"token": "eeNFUXuDQ:APA91bGaLh5UeJcyJctFWlvC32ezPk7ZWp-D05ImpPWbSv_yc49igOioyBOMZg3bxl8L8fvNWTQW6LcptwZoiOwHtIN24uNHox1s2ql1Ir5Rm9Jk1DXPAPe79o20GXHZhY04-TRzpaXe"
}
}
```

Message sent to Firebase for delivery, response:

```
{  
"name": "projects/lacoya-1540956670279/messages/0:1544690320409950%b4fb2744b4fb2744"
}
```

But, in my android device, I'm getting only title value `"FCM Notification"` as a notification but I want to see some data as well like some custom JSON.

Please through some light if you face this earlier.

Regards,

Comment: Is that your actual token or did you change it a bit?

Comment: Can you post your android code

Comment: @Reda I am using java based client code to send push notification to my registered android device for getting notification. This is client code https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/blob/0dec937756dc72c7350e782f73f79a63233bb9a2/messaging/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/Messaging.java#L33    I don't have android code. I just want if I send message using my java client, that should appear as a notification to device.

Comment: @SSingh Yes, the http post request seems to be okey, idk about the message json object, so without the android code to get the data, I don't know how we can figure it out.

Comment: Test like this way : [Test FCM Notification with Postman](https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3)

Comment: Can you post your receiving client's (your android device) code? What are you using to receive only the "title value" ?

Answer (score -1):

There was some some problem with android code. After using correct callback method, we are getting data. Below is the useful link.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Thanks for all of your efforts.